# Display multiple uitable objects in the same figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I would like to display several tables in the same MATLAB figure, much the same as subplot can be used to display multiple graphs. However, it seems that subplot does not apply to uitable objects.

[image: Failed attempt]

As you can see, instead of five tables distributed across the figure, I am getting five sets of empty axes, and only one of the tables is visible.

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

EDIT: Much better after applying the answer supplied below!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of a uitable is a figure or uipanel itself.  So, you can use the tables units and position properties to manually set the tables position within the figure or uipanel. If `t` is the handle to a table created by `t=uitable(...)` then you can use `set(t,'units'...)` and `set(t,'position',[left buttom widht height])` to position the table appropriately.

Here is a specific example

```
f=figure
dd=rand(5,4); %# data
colnames = {'1' '2' '3' 'weight'}
for i=1:4
    t(i) = uitable(f,'columnname',colnames, ...
                     'data',dd, ...
                     'units','normalized', ...
                     'pos',[(i-1)/4 0 .25 1])
end
```